# Use of poesy vs poetry in a concrete example

Tags: word-choice

It seems that similar questions have been asked about the difference between the three terms in the title, but I have a twist: I wrote the line

> Arthur C. Clarke waltzed from the realm of Science Fiction into Mathematical Poetry when he dreamed up the geometry of the famous monolith in his novel 2001: A Space Odyssey.

I was happy with the effect, until I noticed that 'poetry' and 'geometry' rhyme, breaking the rhythm.

Even though the original choice is correct, is it acceptable to substitute 'Poesy' just for avoiding the consonance?

I know I can write however I like; please avoid that type of answer. My question is concretely about the different impressions created on you the readers.

Comment: _Poetry_ and _geometry_ don't rhyme in American English; two words both ending in the same unstressed syllable, with different stress patterns, and nothing else in common, don't rhyme. Except maybe in a rock song, but these words are unlikely to come up there.

Comment: Poesy is an unusual word, and using it might be a bigger distraction from the meaning you are trying to convey. I didn't notice a rhyme, and because all the rhyming syllables are unstressed I don't think it matters.